# Examples of spaces where compact convergence is not equivalent to local uniform convergence.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n: X \to Y$ be a sequence of functions where $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is a metric space. We know that if $X$ is locally compact then local uniform convergence of $f_n$ is equivalent to compact convergence of $f_n$. Now, local uniform convergence always implies compact convergence but in general, compact convergence need not imply local uniform convergence. The only example that I found on internet of such a space where both are not equivalent is here https://www.acritch.com/media/math/Compact_vs._local_uniform_convergence.pdf

I want to know if other such examples are known.